# Candy Machine v2. What to do after withdrawal. Devnet

Tags: solana, candy-machine

I was playing around the candy machine and used withdraw_all command for my candy machine. Now I want to setup a a minting website, but because I closed down the machine. Basically when I try to create a new candy machine, it tells me that "the unique machine already exists". But when I try to interact with it (mint, upload, verify upload) it says "the account doesn't exist. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there is .cache folder. Deleting that folder will allow you to create an completely new candy machine.